# How to handle background/foreground delegates in custom view controllers

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, background, appdelegate

I have got an application which has a `SynchViewController`. It is possible that when the synch view controller is active the application goes to background and comes some days later back into the foreground. In this case I have to reload the already displayed synch view controller. Now - my question. What is the best implementation to achieve this? Do I subscribe to a notification called `reloadSynch` in my `SynchViewController` and then in the `applicationWillEnterForeground` in my `AppDelegate` I send a notification? Or is that a bad idea?

What is the *Best Practice* for this case?

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can observe UIApplication's notifications: `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` and `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification`.

Comment: Thats exactly what I searched for. Thanks a lot!